# How can I print multiple outcomes of the same records in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, string-function

I have the below table which is ordered by the column "CaseID".

[image]

I need to print the output in the below displayed manner where all the outcomes have been grouped together for each cases using commas. I have written the below query to get everything else but not sure how to append all the outcomes.

```
SELECT 
    c.CaseID AS 'Case #',
    c.EventDate AS 'Date',
    CONCAT(d.DrugName+'-',m.ManufacturerName) AS 'Drug & Manufacturer',
    CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.Age)+' ',a.AgeUnitName) AS 'Age',
    c.Sex,
    ou.OutcomeName
FROM
    Consumes con
INNER JOIN 
    [Case] c ON con.FKCaseID = c.CaseID
INNER JOIN 
    Drug d ON d.DrugID = FKDrugID
INNER JOIN 
    Manufacturer m ON m.ManufacturerID = con.FKManufacturerID
INNER JOIN 
    AgeUnit a ON a.AgeUnitID = c.FKAgeUnitID
INNER JOIN 
    Case_Outcome oc ON oc.FKCaseID = c.CaseID
INNER JOIN 
    OutCome ou ON oc.FKOutcomeID = ou.OutcomeID
GROUP BY   
    c.CaseID, c.EventDate, d.DrugName, 
    m.ManufacturerName, c.Age, a.AgeUnitName, c.Sex, ou.OutcomeName
```

[image]

How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean "grouped together"?  SQL result sets are in a tabular format, as shown in your first example.  If you want to structure the data differently for a report, that is best done at the application layer.

Comment: No I meant the outcomes column in the 2nd table has all the outcomes of each row appended together. I need to get that format at the sql layer level :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your query in CTE, then use `FOR XML`:

```
;WITH cte AS (
--your query goes here
)

SELECT c.[Case #],
       c.[Date],
       c.[Drug & Manufacturer],
       c.[Age],
       c.[Sex],
       STUFF((SELECT ','+OutcomeName
       FROM cte
       WHERE c.[Case #] = [Case #]
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as OutcomeName
FROM cte c
GROUP BY c.[Case #],
       c.[Date],
       c.[Drug & Manufacturer],
       c.[Age],
       c.[Sex]
```